# Swift app renders a black screen on ios 8.x

Tags: ios, swift

I have a very basic app:

- one view controller
- image background w/3 labels
- one button

When I run my app on iOS 9 no problem. On iOS 8.x: black screen.

here is my AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        window = UIWindow(frame: frame)

        let rootView: HomeViewController = HomeViewController()

        if let window = self.window{
            window.rootViewController = rootView

            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager().configureWithIdentifier(Config.HOCKEY_APP_IDENTIFIER);
        BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager().startManager();
        BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager().authenticator.authenticateInstallation();


        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

        return true
}
```

- bitcode is turned off.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check to see that you have a loading image?

Comment: do you mean launch images? Yes I have those.

Comment: To help debug, change the window background color to red, for example. Then set the background color of `HomeViewController` to blue, for example. Run the app. What color do you see?

Comment: blue. So, doesn't like the xib ?? that's strange. Seems like none of the elements in the xib are being rendered.

Comment: Update your question with the init method(s) of your `HomeViewController` class.

Comment: no init methods in the HomeViewController class.  Just the empty viewDidLoad.

Comment: Then how do you expect the xib to be loaded if you don't explicitly make use of it?

Comment: @cbrulak your `HomeViewController` is loaded from separate xib or storyboard?

Comment: @rmaddy I declared the UIViewController as a HomeViewController, when I created the classes.

Comment: But the code you implemented doesn't reference the xib. See the answer below.

Comment: @rmaddy I set it as the 'File's Owner' in interface builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same bug in 8.0 for loading view controller from xib files. And that helped me:

```
let controller = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
```

`NSBundle.mainBundle()` was the key that helped me. By default he couldn't find xib file in the bundle

Comment: that was it. Why is that required for iOS 8 though? that doesn't make in any sense.   I set it as the 'File's Owner' in interface builder.

Comment: @cbrulak not sure. Dealed a lot time ago with it, so don't remember the details, sorry. You project is pure swift? Or objective-c too?

Answer (score 0):

I had this bug with Xcode 8.3.3 and target iOS 8.0.

This bug occurs when the developer create a UIWindow.

If you are using Swift 3.1, use this:

```
self.window = UIWindow()
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
self.window?.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

self.window?.rootViewController = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you customizing the HomeViewController in the XIB or StoryBoard?

Because you are not using then to load the HomeViewController object

```
let rootView = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)
```

or customize a init method

```
convenience init() {   
               self.init(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)
   }
```

and use like before

```
let rootView = HomeViewController()
```

Comment: in the Xib. No storyboards.

Comment: Why would I need to do that? Is that specific to iOS 8? because on iOS 9 it runs fine. I also never needed to do that in objc, so why in swift?

Comment: I do not know why did worked on IOS 9, but initialize a UIViewController using the default init will not link the view controller with the Xib elements.